# Pandas groupby average after slicing over non-zero values across remaining groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Hi Consider the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,1,1,1], [1,1,2,0], [1,2,1,1], [1,2,2,0], [2,1,1,0], [2,1,2,0], [2,2,1,1], [2,2,2,1]]), columns = ['k1','k2','k3','v'])
print(a)

   k1  k2  k3  v
0   1   1   1  1
1   1   1   2  0
2   1   2   1  1
3   1   2   2  0
4   2   1   1  0
5   2   1   2  0
6   2   2   1  1
7   2   2   2  1
```

I want to compute how `v` varies with respect to `k1` and am therefore grouping over `k1` and computing the mean.

```
print(a.groupby('k1').mean()['v'])

k1
1    0.5
2    0.5
```

However we can see that when `k2` = 1 and `k3`= 2, value of `v` is always 0 (for both `k1` = 1 and 2). I wish to ignore such rows. So, in order to filter such groups of `k2` and `k3` I am doing the following

```
b = (a.groupby(['k2','k3']).mean()['v']!=0).reset_index()
b = b[b['v']]
del b['v']
print(b)

   k2  k3
0   1   1
2   2   1
3   2   2


c = a.merge(b, how='inner', on=['k2','k3'])
print(c)

   k1  k2  k3  v
0   1   1   1  1
1   2   1   1  0
2   1   2   1  1
3   2   2   1  1
4   1   2   2  0
5   2   2   2  1
```

And then finally taking grouped mean over `k1` I get a better/desirable metric.

```
print(c.groupby('k1').mean()['v'])
k1
1    0.666667
2    0.666667
```

Is there any simpler way to implement this computation since it seems like a pretty common analysis approach but required a pretty long chain of operations

Comment: are you looking to chain them into a single line in which case try: `a.merge(a.groupby(['k2','k3']).mean().query('v!=0').index.to_frame().reset_index(drop=True),
on=['k2','k3']).groupby('k1')['v'].mean()`

Comment: Oh I see, yes query method does simplify the task a little. Thanks

Comment: @Naman Check `a[~(a['k2'].eq(1) & a['k3'].eq(2))].groupby('k1')['v'].mean()`

Comment: Hi, this is just a toy example. I can't manually check all combinations of `k1` and `k2` everytime

Comment: @Naman Then I guess you can try `a[~a['v'].eq(0).groupby([a['k2'], a['k3']]).transform('all')].groupby('k1')['v'].mean()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments and answers from @anky, @Shubham, @ami and @vbn -- some simplifications on code might be

- using query method to filter rows with v=0
- using transform method instead of directly grouping and joining later

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,1,1,1], [1,1,2,0], [1,2,1,1], [1,2,2,0], [2,1,1,0], [2,1,2,0], [2,2,1,1], [2,2,2,1]]), columns = ['k1','k2','k3','v'])
>>> print(a)
   k1  k2  k3  v
0   1   1   1  1
1   1   1   2  0
2   1   2   1  1
3   1   2   2  0
4   2   1   1  0
5   2   1   2  0
6   2   2   1  1
7   2   2   2  1
>>> 
>>> ## method 1
... out = a[a.groupby(['k2', 'k3']).transform(pd.Series.mean)['v']!=0].groupby('k1').mean()['v']
>>> print(out)
k1
1    0.666667
2    0.666667
Name: v, dtype: float64
>>> 
>>> ## method 2
... out = a.merge(a.groupby(['k2','k3']).mean().query('v!=0').index.to_frame().reset_index(drop=True), on=['k2','k3']).groupby('k1')['v'].mean()
>>> print(out)
k1
1    0.666667
2    0.666667
Name: v, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

> However we can see that when k2 = 1 and k3= 2, value of v is always 0 (for both k1 = 1 and 2). I wish to ignore such rows.

If you check the standard error:

```
(a.groupby(['k2','k3']).transform(pd.Series.std) > 0).v
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5    False
6    False
7     True
Name: v, dtype: bool
```

it shows the rows where the rows are not constant for v. You can filter out on this.

Answer (score 1):

You could use query method to filter out the unwanted combination as given below.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


a = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1,1,1,1], [1,1,2,0], [1,2,1,1], [1,2,2,0], [2,1,1,0], [2,1,2,0], [2,2,1,1], [2,2,2,1]]), columns = ['k1','k2','k3','v'])

a = a.query('v != 0 or k2 == k3')

print(a.groupby('k1').mean()['v'])
```

results into:

```
k1
1    0.666667
2    0.666667
```

Comment: What is the point of `k2==k3`? If the second row has `v = 1` then I don't wish to filter any row but this code will still filter the sixth row. I wish to filter a row only when value is zero for all groups of `[k2, k3]`

Comment: @Naman - the query criteria - you know better - what I have demonstrated - is a way to filter out - without going through the multiple statement you were doing in your question posted above, so please use the query method accordingly...

Comment: Oh, right. Yeah using query method is quite simpler thanks.